# Does an extension exist on EXTJS4.2 to create ExtJS 5 like Chained stores

Tags: javascript, extjs4.2, extjs-mvc, sencha-architect

Does an extension exist on EXTJS4.2  to create ExtJS 5 like Chained stores, it's a useful feature.

Comment: No, the underlying architectural changes required to make it happen is fairly large.